# Disable XPM for smartphone/tablet

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, dd4t, 2013-sp1

We have Experience Manager (XPM) enabled on our staging site. This is intended behaviour. When accessing the staging site, it is trying to load `Bootstrap.aspx` via `/WebUI/Editors/siteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js`. This is very slow/timing out. I'm assuming that the loading of `Bootstrap.aspx` has something to do with Experience Manager.

For testing purposes we would only want XPM enabled on a desktop device. Is there some way to disable XPM for mobile/tablet devices, using some form of device detection?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed the Bootstrap script is there because XPM is enabled, it basically adds the Start button to your site, from which you load the XPM interface.

If it is slow in loading, then it sounds to me like the network your mobile devices are on don't have decent access to the CMS website (where the Bootstrap script is located).

But besides that I can understand your wish in wanting it to be disabled on mobile devices, since inline editing on a smartphone never made sense to me (by the way XPM's interface is touch enabled and designed to be used on a table also).

How to disable it depends on your implementation, what Templating model you use etc, and what you did to enable XPM in general. You can use [SDL Mobile](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-99A3E8D8-9F7B-4AA6-B0F9-D015F2389D74) for device detection.

Comment: +1 to mobile - If you have server side device detection then it's trivial to add a condition around the XPM init scripts so that it only loads if the device != mobile.

Comment: The XPM init scripts, where would I find them? What code adds `Bootstrap.aspx` onto the page? Site edit is configured within the `siteedit_config.xml` file, and JavaScript loaded onto the page through `/WebUI/Editors/siteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js` is presumably what reads the enabled flag of the siteedit config file and adds the site edit button onto the page. Is that correct?

Comment: @HaraldGreve unfortunately my crystal ball is broken so I don't know what implementation you have or what Templating model you use. Please edit your question and update the information in there so everybody can see and help provide a more detailed answer. If you are using DD4T the answer will be completely different than when you are using DXA or DWT Templating for example.

Comment: On the final page - the one served to your browser - there is a `
<script>` tag - typically added to the end of the page, after the `</body>` that loads that bootstrap. That's the "XPM init tag" I referred to